# Reprojecting geospatial data north/east to east/north

Tags: gis, geojson, geoserver

I'm getting this GeoJSON from Geoserver.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Sensores propios.4022","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[41.64893,-0.88499]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{}},...
```

However, so as to display this data on a map, I'd like to retrieve it in east/north order. In the example above: [-0.88499,41.64893]. How could I query GeoServer so as to obtain what I want?

Comment: What about loading the GeoJSON using [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) and accessing the coordinates using [ST_X](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [ST_Y](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html)?

Comment: ask for version 2.0.0 instead of 1.0.0 or 1.1.0